# Influx DB Java how to show tags associated with field

Tags: java, influxdb

I have a question on accessing tag using Java.

Here is a query that works great in the UI, with the results shown in the image below.

```
from(bucket: "events")
  |> range(start: -3h)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "NORCA-SYSTEM-TIMESERIES")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "objectCount" or r["_field"] == "norcaErrorCount")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "sum")
```

[image: Query results]

From the above, you can see it returns results from two systems for two variables

Here is the Java code which executes the same query:

```
@Override
    public List<INorcaTotalsSystemDateDTO> norcaInfluxSystemTotalsByTimeUnit
    (String systemName,
            String org,
            String bucket,
            String cacheDatabase,
            String groupByTimeUnit,
            String startFromTimeUnit) {
        String token = NorcaInfluxUtilsService.getInfluxToken();
        String host = "http://localhost:8086";
    
        LOG.info("running influx client");
        InfluxDBClient client = NorcaInfluxUtilsService.getInfluxClient(host, token, org, bucket);
        Map<LocalDateTime, INorcaTotalsSystemDateDTO> dtoMap = new HashMap<>();
        Long norcaErrors = null;
        Long objectCount = null;
        String query = null;
        
        if (!systemName.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
        
                query = "from(bucket: \"events\")" +
                  "  |> range(start: "
                + startFromTimeUnit + ")"
                + "  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] == \"NORCA-SYSTEM-TIMESERIES\") "
                + "  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"System\"] == \""
                + systemName
                + "\") "
                + "  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_field\"] == \"objectCount\" or r[\"_field\"] == \"norcaErrorCount\") "
                + "  |> aggregateWindow(every: "
                + groupByTimeUnit
                + ", fn: sum, createEmpty: false) "
                + "  |> yield(name: \"sum\")";
        }
        else {
            query = "from(bucket: \"events\")\r\n" +
                    "  |> range(start: -3h)\r\n" +
                    "  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] == \"NORCA-SYSTEM-TIMESERIES\")\r\n" +
                    "  |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_field\"] == \"objectCount\" or r[\"_field\"] == \"norcaErrorCount\")\r\n" +
                    "  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)\r\n" +
                    "  |> yield(name: \"sum\")";
            
        }
        
        List<FluxTable> tables = client.getQueryApi().query(query, org);
        LOG.info("read from influx");
        for (FluxTable table : tables) {
            for (FluxRecord record : table.getRecords()) {
                LOG.error(record.getTime() + " " + record.getMeasurement() + " " + record.getField() + " " + record.getValue());
                // System.out.println(record.getTime() + " " + record.getMeasurement() + " " + record.getField() + " " + record.getValue());
            
                Instant instant = record.getTime();
                // ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("UTC");
                ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
                LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zone);
                INorcaTotalsSystemDateDTO currentDTO = dtoMap.get(localDateTime);
                if (currentDTO == null) {
                    currentDTO = new NorcaTotalsSystemDateDTO();
                    dtoMap.put(localDateTime, currentDTO);
                    
                    Map<String, Object> tempMap = null;
                    tempMap = record.getValues();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : tempMap.entrySet())
                    {
                        System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + "; value: " + entry.getValue());
                    }
                    currentDTO.setSystemName((String)tempMap.get("System"));
                    currentDTO.setBarcodeType((String)tempMap.get("barcodeType"));
            
                }
                else {
                    LOG.info("current DTO was found! " + localDateTime);
                }
                String formatted = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(localDateTime);
                                
                currentDTO.setScanDate(formatted);
                if (record.getField().equalsIgnoreCase("objectCount")) {
                
                    objectCount = (Long) record.getValue();
                    currentDTO.setTotalFeatures((objectCount.intValue()));
                }
                if (record.getField().equalsIgnoreCase("norcaErrorCount")) {
                    
                    norcaErrors = (Long) record.getValue();
                    currentDTO.setNonZeroFeatures(norcaErrors.intValue());
                }
                
                
            } // checked all rows
        }
```

When the systemName is "all", it executes the second query

```
query = "from(bucket: \"events\")\r\n" +
                    " |> range(start: -3h)\r\n" +
                    " |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] == \"NORCA-SYSTEM-TIMESERIES\")\r\n" +
                    " |> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_field\"] == \"objectCount\" or r[\"_field\"] == \"norcaErrorCount\")\r\n" +
                    " |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)\r\n" +
                    " |> yield(name: \"sum\")";
```

When I try to access the tags with this code (as shown above)

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : tempMap.entrySet())
                    {
                       System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + "; value: " + entry.getValue());
                    }
```

It only prints out one of the four lines - System "01" and barcode "r"
There should be four, as shown in the graph

How can I see all the tags?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It turns out a separate row can have exactly the same date but different tags. Maybe rows can actually be though of as columns in a relational db?